# Can i access request parameter in jackson BeanSerializerModifier?

Tags: jersey, jackson

I am using Jersey to implement rest api and Jackson to provide JSON support. I am trying to remove certain properties before serialization by overriding [BeanSerializerModifier.changeProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) method.

But removing properties will be based on query parameter. Is there any way to access the query parameter in my implementation?

Comment: What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: I am using Jersey 2.6. Can i make use of ThreadLocal to share query parameter info to outside resource?

Comment: If you can switch to a later version (not sure, either 2.17 or 2.19), there is Jackson support for [Entity Data Filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html). It supports filtering with query parameters

Comment: True.. We evaluated that entity data filtering feature and some of the supporting JAR requires JDK 1.7 and we need to stick to JDK 1.6 for some reason. So we ruled out that option.

Comment: Entity filtering has been available since 2.3, but initially it only supported MOXy. If you look at the bottom of the documentation, you will see that it is extensible. Jersey uses this extensibility to provide support for Jackson later. You can look at the [provider used](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java) to implement this feature in later version, if you want to try and incorporate yourself into 2.6

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and some reason it (Entity Filtering based on query parameters) is not working in 2.6 and i don't see error also :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `BeanSerializerModifier` itself would get complicated as the method is only called once when construction necessarily `JsonSerializer` for the first time. As to passing query parameters, you could pass them using contextual attributes and `ObjectWriter` (constructed from `ObjectMapper`), but that means taking over quite a bit of serialization automation from Jersey.

There is one mechanism that could be helpful in modifying serialization aspects without taking over the whole process: registering `ObjectWriterModifier`, using `ObjectWriterInjector`. These are part of Jackson JAX-RS provider, added in Jackson 2.3. Without knowing more details I don't know how easy this would be; part of the issue is that query parameters are more of an input side things, so there is no direct access to them from output processing side.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using Jackson 2.2 :(

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand BeanSerializerModifier behavior, So the BeanSerializerModifier will be invoked during the serialization object creation for the first time and this object will be cached. For the subsequent requests the object will not be created (it will be served from Cache) so the BeanSerializerModifier  will not be invoked? 

Many thanks.

Comment: @Mkm correct. Only the serializer you construct will be invoked after the initial call.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i have found in my implementation, basically i kept the logic to change the properties inside the BeanSerializerModifier.changeProperties() thinking that this will be invoked for all time before the serialization. Now i have changed my implementation as below

Comment: Now i have changed my implementation as below                                public class CustomBeanPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {
  private final BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriterObj;
  protected CustomBeanPropertyWriter(final BeanPropertyWriter base) {
    super(base);
    this.beanPropertyWriterObj = base;
  }

  @Override
  public void serializeAsField(final Object bean, final JsonGenerator jgen,
    final SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
 if(this property can be seralized)
 {super.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, prov);
 }
  }
 }

Comment: public class CustomBeanSerializerModifierImpl extends BeanSerializerModifier {
  @Override
  public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(
    final SerializationConfig config, final BeanDescription beanDesc,
    final List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
    final ListIterator<BeanPropertyWriter> iter =
      beanProperties.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      final BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriter = iter.next();
      iter.set(new CustomBeanPropertyWriter(beanPropertyWriter));
    }
    return beanProperties;
  }
}